# Is the infinitive in this sentence correct?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

> John was fortunate to receive the funding.

The statement uses the infinitive "to receive" instead of "to have received," which describes the state of having received something. "to have received" is correct because fortunate has the sense of describing a state instead of something dynamic like what is suggested by "to receive."

Is "to receive" correct grammar and why?

Comment: Hi, Joe. I am sure your English teacher from High School is proud of your attention to detail. I would consider the subtle distinction between "to receive" and "to have received" to be an interesting discussion of style. The use of "to receive" gets a grammatical green light.

Comment: It is interesting in that it appears that both convey the same sense of receiving something in the past due to "was fortunate." The first version also is backtrack the receipt with respect to speaker's timeline due to the past tense; that sense is not limited to the second version. However the only difference is that the first makes it seem like a on shot transactional thing versus the other.

Comment: Generally, the main verb establishes the absolute time frame of the sentence, and all the other verbal phrases establish a relative time frame.

Answer (score 1):

Both usages are idiomatic.

The main verb "*was*" establishes John's fortunate state of being in the past with respect to the speaker.

> John was fortunate.

Adding the past perfect infinitive phrase "*to have received the funding*", adds details of John's fortunate state, showing that receipt of the funding shifts **farther back** in time with respect to the speaker's timeline.

> "John was fortunate to have received the funding"

Adding the plain infinitive phrase "*to receive the funding*", adds similar detail to John's fortunate state, but shows **no shift** with respect to the speakers timeline.

> "John was fortunate to receive the funding"

Both constructions of the infinitive are grammatically correct.

Comment: I am curious, @Erik Kowal , about them being "idiomatic".

Comment: @ScotM - In other words, they would come naturally to a native speaker.

Comment: @ScotM The principal usage (as seen by its being listed first by non-historic dictionaries) of 'idiomatic', 'sounding natural to a native speaker', does not match the principal usage of 'idiom' in linguistics, 'a phrase etc in wide use but having unusual use of words and/or not employing normal grammar'.

Comment: That was the source of my curiosity, @EdwinAshworth, a technical distinction that I can appreciate.